# Select Most Recently Updated Row Based on Sequence ID with Three Tables

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I've [previously asked how to use a sequence ID to select the most recently updated row](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/52080/6463), but I'm not quite sure how to apply it to a more advanced query involving multiple joins. Here is my current query:

```
select
  p.Person_ID,
  p.Person_Name,
  p.Person_Age,
  d.Department_Name,
  c.Company_Name,
  c.Company_City,
  c.Company_State
from Person p
left join Department d 
  on p.Person_Department_ID=d.Department_ID
left join (
  select Company_ID, Company_Name, Company_City, Company_State
  from Company
  group by Company_ID, Company_Name, Company_City, Company_State
) as c on c.Company_ID=d.Department_Company_ID
where c.Company_ID=1
```

I have made [an example on SQLFiddle for this question](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/97f45/1/0). I want to only select the most recent Person (`max(Person_Seq_ID)`), and only show the most up-to-date Department name next to that Person (`max(Department_Seq_ID)`). There should only be seven records returned in [my uploaded example.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/97f45/1/0) How do I do this?

Note that only Person and Department have sequence IDs—not Company.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I missed something, the following will give you what is needed :

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
select
  p.Person_ID,
  p.Person_Name,
  p.Person_Age,
  d.Department_Name,
  c.Company_Name,
  c.Company_City,
  c.Company_State,
  p.Person_Seq_ID,
  d.Department_ID,
  d.Department_Seq_ID,

  MAX(p.Person_Seq_ID) OVER(PARTITION BY p.Person_ID) as mPerson,
  MAX(d.Department_Seq_ID) OVER(PARTITION BY p.Person_ID, d.Department_ID) as mDep

from Person p
left join Department d 
  on p.Person_Department_ID=d.Department_ID
left join (
  select Company_ID, Company_Name, Company_City, Company_State
  from Company
  group by Company_ID, Company_Name, Company_City, Company_State
) as c on c.Company_ID=d.Department_Company_ID
where c.Company_ID=1
  ) a 
WHERE Person_Seq_ID = mPerson and Department_Seq_ID = mDep
```

[Here is an updated link showing this on SQLFiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/97f45/15/0)

Comment: I don't see the point of the subquery on Company.  That can just be the company table itself, no?

Comment: Any way to make it not show all the keys at the end, though?

Comment: @Max Vernon : You are right , but I didn't pay attention to further optimization - focused on returning desired output.

Comment: @Dan : Absolutely, you can select any columns inside subquery(derived table)